# How to extend ReportNG?

Tags: java, testng, reportng

I am using TestNG to configure my tests and using ReportNG for reporting.

**Code Set up**

I have a class that has a TestNG data provider which is configured with parallel=true and for every element that Data Provider provides, different threads are spawned (thread count is configurable) to run a @Test

**Question**

The reportNG result looks nice and appears something like below in html

> MyTestName     0.297s Method arguments: "URL1"
>
> MyTestName     0.156s Method arguments: "URL2"

Based on the logic in my @Test MyTestName, I would like to pass/fail @Test and print messages which will appear in ReportNG report. How would I do this that would be thread safe? could some one point me to sample examples?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using Reporter.log()? (it's part of the TestNG API)

Comment: Hi Cedric, My @ Test (only one test) runs on a data provider that is running multiple threads..Would you recommend something like below in my @ Test if(pass) { Reporter.log("nice thing happened");} else { Assert.fail("something wrong happened"); }

Comment: Yes. Reporter.log() is thread safe, why don't you try it and report back?